# Installing DLC Oblivion GOTY Edition on XBox One

Tags: xbox-one, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I've installed Oblivion GOTY on my XBox One, when I did this I used Disc One of the two discs in the case. I found out today (and several hours into my game) that in order to have my XBox One 'see' the other DLC included with the GOTY Edition I actually have to install Disc 2 from the start.

My worry is that by uninstalling the game I'll also lose all progress I've made thus far. When I go to Manage Game I do see there's a section for 'Saved Data' that's 10MB, if I uninstall the game itself but leave this section intact, will I still have my saved games when I re-install with the DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about save integrity, you might want to look into [Xbox Cloud Storage.](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/cloud-save-games) For existing save files, follow these instructions to ensure they are on the cloud:

```
1. Sign in to your Xbox profile.
2. Go to settings, and then select System.
3. Select Storage.
4. Select the storage device that contains the saved game that you 
      want to move to the cloud.
5. Select Games.
6. Select the game with your saved game.
7. Select your saved game.
8. Select Move.
9. Select Cloud Saved Games.
```

This will ensure that even if your save files are erased, you will have a backup on the Xbox Cloud. However, save files are typically untouched when uninstalling games, at least on other platforms. Better safe than sorry though!